# Push associative array to an existing associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm fetching data from a MySQL query into a private $this->_data.
But I am also filling in the data from another table to $this->_data.
Is there an easier way to do this ?

```
$this->_data = $row; # This fetches data from a MySQL query

# This works
$this->_data['Salary'] = '';
.
.
.
$this->_data['Growth'] = '';

# This doesn't. Give s Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ']'
$this->_data['Salary' => '',
             .
             .
             .
             'Growth' => ''
             ];
```

Comment: The last example is the syntax you would use to initialize a new array, but `_data` is already initialized at that point. You can then only access individual elements as in the first two examples.

Comment: Not to overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```php
$this->_data = $row;
// ...
$this->_data = array_merge($this->_data, [
    'Salary' => '',
    // ...
    'Growth' => '',
]);
```

---

If don't want to merge the results you can keep them in a multidimensional array

```php
$this->_data[] = $row;
$this->_data[] = [
    'Salary' => '',
    // ...
    'Growth' => '',
];

echo $this->_data[0]['Salary']; // This came from the first query
echo $this->_data[1]['Salary']; // This came from the second one
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the data is retrieved through

```
$this->_data = $row; # This fetches data from a MySQL query
```

The associative array could be simple defined as follows

`$this->_data = ['Salary' => '', ... 'Growth' => ''];`

Comment: $this->_data = [] overwrites data.